# Unable to use inheritance with multiple files in f#

Tags: f#

I am having trouble with what seems to be a trivial use of inheritance in an f# project.

File 1:

```
namespace MercurySchool.Models

[<AbstractClass>]
type Resource() =   

    abstract member  Href: string with get, set
    abstract member  Method: string with get, set
    abstract member  Relations: string[] with get, set
    abstract member  Id: int with get, set
    abstract member  Name: string with get, set
    abstract member  Description: string with get, set
```

File 2:

```
namespace MercurySchool.Models

type School() =
    inherit Resource()
```

In File 2 I am getting the following errors:

- `No constructors are available for the type 'Resource'`
- `The type 'Resource' is not defined.`

Feels like there's a simple resolution, but so far it escapes me.

Some background:

- Following example and documentation I have found.[[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/abstract-classes)]
- Using VS 2017 Community. Recently updated.

Comment: Is file 2 listed after file 1 in the order of compilation?

Comment: I saw something about file order. Is that defined in the fsproj file?

Comment: Yes it is defined in the project file

Answer (score 1):

The problem indeed appears to be the order of compilation, as Fydor suggested.

I changed the `fsdprog` file from this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Models\*.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to a more explicit declaration:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Models\Resource.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\school.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After a few other changes unrelated to this question, the project builds.